# Retrieving values to do a simple Y=a*x+b & getting an error

Tags: python

I am doing a training for newbies on Python. I am having trouble finishing the last homework.

I want to apply the "coeffs" defined at the start of my code depending on the species of each individual of my sample.

```
coeffs = {
    "cas 1" : {'a': [0.38599421003086465] , 'b':[0.5092683365300003]},
    "cas 2" : {'a': [1.7875014940283396] , 'b':[1.4593274917352779]},
    "cas 3" : {'a': [0.6992505959712975] , 'b':[1.0377429413261892]},
    "cas 4" : {'a': [0.9735704312621848] , 'b':[0.8094893720788445]},
}
lignes_modifiees = []


for (i,individu) in iris.iterrows(): # pour chaque individu de iris,...
    if pd.isnull(individu["petal_width"]): #... on test si individu["petal_width"] est nul.
        a = coeffs["cas 1"]['a']
        b = coeffs["cas 1"]['b']
        X = individu["petal_length"]
        Y = a*X + b
        iris.loc[i,"petal_width"] = Y # on remplace la valeur manquante par Y
        lignes_modifiees.append(i)
        print("On a complété petal_width par {} a partir de petal_length={}".format(Y,X))

    if pd.isnull(individu["sepal_width"]): #... on test si individu["sepal_width"] est nul.
        # je dois appliquer les coeffs de l'espèce, soit 2 si setosa, 3 si virginica et 4 si versicolor
        espece = individu["species"] # je dois appliquer les coeffs de l'espèce, soit 2 si setosa, 3 si virginica et 4 si versicolor
        if individu["species"] == "setosa":
            a = 1.7875014940283396
            b = 1.4593274917352779
        elif individu["species"] == "virginica":
            a = 0.6992505959712975
            b = 1.0377429413261892
        elif individu["species"] == "versicolor":
            a = 0.9735704312621848
            b = 0.8094893720788445
        X = individu["petal_width"]
        Y = a*X + b #ERROR HERE
        iris.loc[i,"sepal_width"] = Y # on remplace la valeur manquante par Y
        lignes_modifiees.append(i)
        print("On a complété sepal_width par {} a partir de l'espece:{} et de petal_width={}".format(Y,espece,X))
```

I am getting the following error for the second main "if" (the first one properly works): TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Ideally, I would like values a & b to retrieve the "coeff" like this:

```
if individu["species"] == "setosa":
       a = coeffs["cas 1"]['a']
       b = coeffs["cas 1"]['b']
```

It does not work neither.

I am very bad at this! Thank you :)

Comment: `Y = a*X + b` what do you want to happen here? It looks like you are multiplying a list with a float and then adding a float. This is results in an error because you can't multiply a list with a float. Do you want to apply `a*item+b` on every item of `X`?

Comment: Thank you!

The exercise aims at finding the missing value of a data frame. I have calculated the coeffs needed to find the missing sepal_width. So sepal_width = coeff a * petal_width + coeff b 

I want coeff a & coeff b to have different values depending on the species of my individual, e.g. if individual's species is "setosa", a and b should have the values of coeffs["cas 2"], if individual's species is "virginica", a and b should have the values of coeffs["cas 3"]. Sorry if I am unclear!